# How to delete second column notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this file :

```
example-site1.com      site-site1.com     user1    password1
example-site2.com   site-site2.com    user2    password2
example-site3.com      site-site3.com    user3    password3
```

there are irregular spaces, and i want to add port **80** behind the site and the **@** character

i need to arrange the words like this :

```
example-site1.com:80@user1@password1
example-site2.com:80@user2@password2
example-site3.com:80@user3@password3
```

can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+)\h+\S+\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)`
- Replace with: `$1:80@$2@$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (\S+)     # group 1, 1 or more non spaces (domain)
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \S+       # 1 or more non spaces
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (\S+)     # group 2, 1 or more non spaces (user)
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (\S+)     # group 3, 1 or more non spaces (password)
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1
:80@    # literally :80@
$2      # content of group 2
@       # literally @
$3      # content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]